# nginx: disable HTTP responses for SSL port completely

Tags: nginx, https

I have a private HTTPS server using nginx. Therefore, I don't care about browser compatibility nor HTTP to HTTPS redirection; I just want it to work in my environment and nowhere else. I have already configured it with "listen 17648 ssl;". Whenever I try to connect to it using plain HTTP, I get the infamous "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" response.

Is there any way to prevent nginx from sending any response at all when a HTTP request is sent to a HTTPS port? I would like nginx to simply close the connection if the request is not SSL, or maybe return some SSL-level error but no plain HTTP response at all, not even an error response.

Answer (score 3):

From Nginx documentation about the [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) clause:

> The non-standard code 444 closes a connection without sending a response header.

So I've tried to catch the error 497 "HTTP to HTTPS" and tried to return the 444 this way:

```
error_page 497 =444 @close;

location @close {
   return 444;
}
```

Unfortunately this leads to a "pending" state due to this [bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/274)

Using the workaround proposed by the developer it seems to work:

```
error_page 497 =444 @close;

location @close {
   return 0;
}
```

Try if this fits your needs!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in my case (nginx 1.6.2). curl -v shows that the server is still sending a reply with status code 444 and there are several headers, including the Server header.